# Set correctly SignalR-hub configuration with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-service, signalr-hub

I following this [tutorial](http://mahedee.net/a-signalr-application-for-real-time-notification-using-angularjs-and-toastr/) to implement push notifications with SignalR and toastr

before implement it my app.js is like:

```
  (function () {
        'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myPortal', ['common.core', 'common.ui'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    /* Setup global settings */
    app.factory('settings', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        // supported languages
        var settings = {....
```

when I update it as tutorial I have something like this:

```
(function () {
        'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myPortal', ['common.core', 'common.ui'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });


    $.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + err);
    });

    angular.module('app')
       .value('notification', $.connection.notification)
       .value('toastr', toastr);


    /* Setup global settings */
    app.factory('settings', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        // supported languages
        var settings = {...
```

but now my app crash and chrome console throw these issues:

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.

and

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: settingsProvider <-
>   settings

What am I doing wrong? Regards